# Valor do input text não vem com o outerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu preciso armazenar um código HTML no banco de dados. Eu consigo gerar esse HTML e exibi-lo em uma modal da forma como eu quero.

Porém quando vou salvar ele no banco, tenho que rodar o comando:

`var $texto = $html.prop('outerHTML');`

para passar como parâmetro a varíavel `$texto` para o AJAX... o que acontece é que utilizando o outerHTML todos os valores dos campos são perdidos e eu não consigo encontrar uma solução para isso.

Lembrando que a variável $html quando coloco para ser exibida em um modal tem todos os valores:

```
swal({
  title: "Correção",
  html: $html
});
```

Simplificando eu utilizo o outerHTML para transformar o HTML em string, porém quando isso acontece os valores dos inputs não vão junto.

Como faço para que os valores dos campos fiquem no código?

Código simplificado:

```
var $html = $('<div />',{html:text});//text tem o HTML vindo do banco

$html.find('[type="text"]').each(function(i){//Esse each popula o formulário
      $(this).prop('value',resposta_aluno[i+1]);
      $(this).prop('disabled', true);
      if(acertos[i] == 0){
        $(this).addClass("exercicio_errado");
      }
    });

var $texto = $html.prop('outerHTML');//transforma o HTML em texto para que possa ser inserido no banco
```

Comment: Explique melhor o seu problema e apresente toda a parte relevante do código.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Simplificando, eu utilizo o outerHTML para transformar o HTML em string, porém quando isso acontece os valores dos inputs não vão junto. e eu preciso que o código no banco contenha os values dos inputs para que já venham preenchidos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para deixar explícito na declaração do elemento, substitua o `$(this).prop('value',resposta_aluno[i+1]);` por `$(this).attr('value',resposta_aluno[i+1]);`

```js
var $html = $('<div />',{html:'<input type="text" />'});//text tem o HTML vindo do banco

$html.find('[type="text"]').each(function(i){//Esse each popula o formulário
      $(this).attr('value',"A");
      $(this).prop('disabled', true);
      
    });

var $texto = $html.prop('outerHTML');//transforma o HTML em texto para que possa ser inserido no banco
console.log($texto);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div />
```

Comment: Valeu cara, é exatamente o que eu precisava!!

Comment: Depois eu vou editar a resposta com a explicação do porque